# Cross-browser method to prevent all methods of text copying from a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, clipboard, copy-paste

I am working on an online typing software. In the typing software, all is going well but I have the problem of dishonest users who might possibly type the text into the textarea, copy it, then reload the page (therefore resetting the timer) and pasting it in straightaway. So I was thinking along the lines of using something like `evt.preventDefault();` when javascript detects the pressing of the ctrl / cmd button along with the `C` key. But then I realized that the user could always go up to the menu bar to press `Edit -> Copy`. So I was wondering, is there a cross-browser method to disable both methods of copying?

Comment: @think123: i have a solution for your previous deleted question (how come my php mysql code only displays one td)

Comment: oh that one is solved (I think). Sorry about that.

Comment: Just remember that nothing you do will prevent people from blocking clipboard events in their browser. For instance, in Firefox we just go to `about:config` and search for `dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled`, and set it to `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use the following jQuery code:

```
$('input[type=text],textarea').bind('copy paste cut drag drop', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: May I ask, what does the bind('copy paste cut' section of your code do? Thanks!

Comment: bind function attaches event handlers to your elements. "copy paste cut" tells us, which events should fire the attached function.

Comment: @think123 it's [jQuery](http://jquery.com) (a javascript library).. here you can see how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/tkmkN/

Comment: Is this solution cross-browser?

Comment: here is a reference for jquery's browser compatibility http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility

Answer (score 2):

You maybe could do something like:

```
var txtArea = document.getElementById("YourTextAreaId");
txtArea.oncopy = function() { return false; } 
txtArea.onpaste = function() { return false; } 
txtArea.oncut = function() { return false; }
```

But even then, the user can copy the content by other means, as suggested in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can block some events, but preventing such user behaviour is not possible. User can always copy text from DOM node via browser console.

Comment: Yeah because everyone knows how to whip out the console and start manipulating dom

Comment: Oh DOM manipulation is not a problem, I mean if the user did not understand DOM manipulation, and only knew things like Edit -> Copy and right-click -> Copy (right-click's not a problem) and CTRL-C and CMD-C. That's what I am mainly worrying about.

Comment: @think123 that doesn't work if you `preventDefault()` from cut/paste/copy events AFAIK

Comment: To me DOM Manipulation is not a problem, because I have got what the user needs to type in a PHP GD image, so I'm not worrying about that.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the event handlers and prevent the clipboard function like such:

```
$('textarea').on('copy paste cut drag drop', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: @Downvoter, Any thing wrong with my answer? Please explain so I can improve it.