# Prevent copy from browser drag drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to prevent users from copying text from my website.

After searching I found a great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070939/cross-browser-method-to-prevent-all-methods-of-text-copying-from-a-textarea)

This does stop copy/paste/cut when using ctrl button combinations and right click menu.

However on testing I was able to drag the content from my TextArea into a word document and into VS2012 from Firefox, Chrome and Safari ... I stopped testing the rest.

This is my control and the script I am using from the post referenced.

```
<textarea readonly="readonly" draggable="false" >
    blah blah
</textarea>
```

Script

```
<script>
        $(document).delegate('input[type=text],textarea', 
                             'copy paste cut drag drop', 
                              function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
</script>
```

I have also tried

```
@Html.TextArea("Blah", "blah"
,new { oncopy= "return false", onpaste="return false", oncut="return false"})
```

but again the drag and drop copy is not prevented.

Is there a sure fire way of preventing text data from leaving the site?

EDIT***  Not sure fire, but a way to make it a more difficult for a common user, the drag and drop method is very easy to understand.

Comment: This is one of the most annoying features of any sites that I use! Whatever you do the user will still be able to view source and get your text from there. You cannot protect content that you send to the browser.

Comment: be sure to have some animated gifs, a nice background tune, and a custom mouse pointer

Comment: Thank you David - I created a .jpg with the section of text I didn't want easily copied and set it as the background of a div. This creates a big enough challenge for a common user and only provides un-editable text. All inspired by your comment.

Answer (score 2):

That is senseless. You've already passed all your content to your user's PC and you are unable to make user do with your text only what you want.

Specifically to copypasting, it is impossible.

Comment: I understand that. I am presuming that most of my users do not have a degree in Computer Science. The drag and drop feature is very simple to operate and understand. Could I make it harder for the common user?

Comment: I fail to see how your comment is either constructive or relevant. Are you not breaking the rules of this site with your patronising and condemning comment?

Comment: @AnimusMiles-Militis well, sorry then, I will delete the comment.